# How can I find the average of a list with multiple cells?

Tags: python

Example: `x = [[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

I attempted to use:

`sum(x) / len(x)` but it seems to give me this error

(TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list')

The list is inputted by the user with command: average_list([]) and could contain any amount of numbers per square brackets.

Comment: Do you want the average of complete list or average of lists inside list?

Comment: I want the average of the complete list! Sorry for not being clear I'm a beginner to this website and Python.

Comment: Also, `sum` does not work on list of lists, it only adds level 1 sub elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `sum` the sums of the inner lists:

```
x = [[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

s = sum(sum(a) for a in x)
l = sum(len(a) for a in x)
print(s / l) # 5.0
```

Comment: This is working, but how would you return 0 if the user left the input empty perhaps? For example x = []

Comment: @NimaYeganeh you can check if `len(x) == 0`. If it is, return 0, otherwise, return the average.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(x)
avg = np.sum(x)/np.size(x) # avg = 5
```

Comment: Why not use numpy's mean method?   `np.array(x).mean()`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [i for sublist in x for i in sublist]
avg = sum(x)/len(x)
```

Here is an answer after flattening the list

Answer (score 0):

This provides you both, the average of the lists of list as well as the average of complete list.

```
x = [[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
new_list = [sum(l)/len(l) for l in x]
print(sum(new_list)/len(new_list))
```

Output:

```
5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A more scholastic way to do this is the following:

```
x = [[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

#stripping square brackets
elementsString = ''.join( c for c in str(x) if  c not in '[]' )

total = 0
numberOfElements = 0

#converting the string numbers into int
for i in elementsString.split(','):
    #using int but can be also float for example
    i = int(i) 
    numberOfElements += 1
    total += i

average = total/numberOfElements
print(average)

#5.0 is the answer in your case
```

Answer (score -2):

are you trying to find the average of the sum of the entire list of (x) or the sum of each cell?

Comment: Trying to find the average of the sum of the entire list.

Comment: @isaac Please ask the clarifications in the comment section.